# I have 2 java errors that I need help! Errors: incomparable types: Scanner and String & bad operand types for binary operator '+'

Tags: java

I have two java errors that I need help on solving, please help!!

Error 1: incomparable types: Scanner and String

Error 2: bad operand types for binary operator '+'

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class calculator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
        x.nextInt();
        Scanner y = new Scanner(System.in);
        y.nextInt();
        Scanner function = new Scanner(System.in);
        function.next();
        if (function == "add") {
            int sum = x + y;
            System.out.println(sum);
        }
```

Comment: This line: `int sum = x + y;` - do you understand what is `x` ? further, you don't need to create a new scanner every time you want the user's input - you can re-use the same one again and again! Look for online examples (there are plenty) to see how it's done.

Comment: Don't make three separate Scanner objects.  Just one will be enough for your needs.

Comment: You might also want to look into what the proper way to compare String objects in Java is.

Comment: Hopefully [this](https://www.javascan.com/369/java-scanner-example) simple example will help you to understand scanner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `+` for a non-primitive type (or `String`). In your case, you try to use it for a `Scanner` reference.

You probably meant:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int x = scanner.nextInt();
int y = scanner.nextInt();
String function = scanner.next();
if (function == "age") {
    int sum = x + y;
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("List of functions: 'age'");
    System.out.println("Please enter the function:");
    String function = reader.next();

    System.out.println("Enter the first age:");
    int x = reader.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter the second age:");
    int y = reader.nextInt();

    if (function.equalsIgnoreCase("age")) {
        int sum = x + y;
        System.out.println("Total is: " + sum);
    }
}
```